# How to create a new data frame where existing columns become a new column in R

Tags: r, kaggle

I'm still very new to R so bare with me.
I have an existing dataset with 33 unique participant Id's and activity dates of 30 days for each of these participants.
I'm interested in the columns VeryActiveMinutes, FairlyActiveMinutes, LightlyActiveMinutes, and SedentaryMinutes.

I want to create a new data frame where these columns become a new column called "Activity Levels" and have another column for their average minutes.
So it would look something like this:

activity levels        avg_activity_minutes

very active
fairly active
lightly active
sedentary

Is it possible to create an output like this?

This is the closest code I've been to getting the data I want but the output looks like its in a wide format rather than long:

```
avg_active_min_levels <- activity %>%
summarize(avg_very = mean(VeryActiveMinutes), avg_fairly = mean(FairlyActiveMinutes), avg_lightly = mean(LightlyActiveMinutes), avg_sedentary = mean(SedentaryMinutes))
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here this is how you can make a quick small example:

```
participants <- 33

my_dat <- data.frame(
    id = 1:participants,
    VeryActiveMinutes = rnorm(participants, 0, 5),
    FairlyActiveMinutes = rnorm(participants, 0, 5),
    LightlyActiveMinutes = rnorm(participants, 0, 5),
    SedentaryMinutes = rnorm(participants, 0, 5)
)
```

This format is called "wide" you want it "tidy" or "long". It look like you are using the tidyverse so I used it.

```
columns <- names(my_dat)[-1] # vector of columns you want to pivot

library(tidyr)

my_dat_tidy <- my_dat %>% 
    tidyr::pivot_longer(cols =  columns,
                        names_to = "activity levels avg_activity_minutes",
                        values_to = "I_do_not_know")
```

Comment: I tried this but the output wasn't quit what I was looking for. The participant Id's arent really necessary, rather the average of all the participants VeryActive, FairlyActive, LightlyActive, and Sedentary Minutes.

Comment: Then I think I misunderstood the structure of the data. Can you use and correct my small example so it match your data (the part where I create a dummy data set) and then can you provide an example of what kind of output will be produced ?